# What's BayesianMinimization and related functions based on?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, machine-learning, neural-networks

Is it specified anywhere what the backend is for the Bayesian optimization related functionality in Mathematica v11? I'm specifically referring to the `Bayesian*` functions like `BayesianMinimization`. Are they based on an open-source package like [Spearmint](https://github.com/HIPS/Spearmint), or on a brand new implementation? For example the neural network functionality is based on MXNet, but I couldn't find any information in the docs about the backend that's being used for Bayesian optimization.

Comment: it seems to use the same implementation of Gaussian Processes as is used by the Predict/Classify framework. this suggests it's probably a brand new implementation.